# Pandas - determine value of column by using a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, timestamp

I am trying to add a new value to my excisting pandas file. My pandas file is a .CSV file I read by using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('coordinatesCSV.csv', sep=';', header=None)
df.columns = ['Longitude','Lattitude']

df.head()
```

The .head part of the Pandas DataFrame looks as follows

```
    Longitude   Lattitude
0   52.379512   4.896694
1   52.379250   4.896995
2   52.379289   4.897574
3   52.378844   4.897918
4   52.378844   4.897918
```

I want to add a new column named 'TimeStamp'. I want this Timestamp to be a random time I generate by using the following code:

```
def random_date(start,l):
   current = start
   while l >= 0:
    current = current + datetime.timedelta(minutes=randrange(10))
    yield current
    l-=1

for x in reversed(list(random_date(startDate,1))):
    df['Timestamp'] = x
```

The problem with my function is that it only calculates one random time and sets this as the value on all the rows I have in my pandas DataFrame, so my dataframe now looks as follows:

```
    Longitude   Lattitude   Timestamp
0   52.379512   4.896694    2013-09-20 13:00:00
1   52.379250   4.896995    2013-09-20 13:00:00
2   52.379289   4.897574    2013-09-20 13:00:00
3   52.378844   4.897918    2013-09-20 13:00:00
4   52.378844   4.897918    2013-09-20 13:00:00
```

How do I make sure my function calculates a new timestamp for every row of my dataframe and not just one timestamp as soon above.
Thank you very much!

Comment: never mind I was sleeping, solved it by adjusting my code: 
df['Timestamp'] = random_date(startDate,1)

Answer (score 0):

When you write `df['Timestamp'] = x`, you set every entry of the `Series` to be `x`. Instead, one way of using your function would be to simply let

```
df['Timestamp'] = list(random_date(startDate, len(df) - 1))[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so would be (assuming that startDate is a column too)

```
df['Timestamp'] = df['startDate'].map(random_date)
```

Another option (assuming that startDate is constant) is to just make a list of the same size as your dataframe. Then you assign that list to the column.

```
df['Timestamp'] = [random_date(startDate,1) for _ in xrange(len(df))]
```